# Airflow - When I start the scheduler it keeps running the same DAG indefinitely

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I implemented a really simple DAG

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2021, 8, 13),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}


with DAG('tutorial',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
         ) as dag:



    scrape_regions_task = PythonOperator(task_id='scrape_regions_task',
                                    python_callable=scrape_regions_task)
```

And now every time I start the scheduler this script runs forever. Previously I had my `start_date` = `dt.datetime(2017, 1, 01)` and I thought that it could just be running all the queued jobs. So I changed the `start_date` and I set all the tasks instances to `success`. But no luck, every time I start the scheduler it just spams the dag.

Any idea what is wrong?

Regards

Comment: Hey Luís! I was wondering if my answer below was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `catchup=False` in the DAG definition:

```py
with DAG('tutorial',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
```

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup):

> An Airflow DAG with a start_date, possibly an end_date, and a schedule_interval defines a series of intervals which the scheduler turns into individual DAG Runs and executes. The scheduler, by default, will kick off a DAG Run for any interval that has not been run since the last execution date (or has been cleared). This concept is called Catchup.